# Does Spring DI create multiple instances while injecting through @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a class A and class B which are using methods from class C.

Class C is a service class annotated with @Service.

To get object instances of class C in class A and B, I have used @Autowired.

This means that Spring will create two object instances, one for class A and one for class B ?

Answer (score 2):

No, **Spring creates singleton (default scope) bean in the IOC container.**

So, only one bean will be created for class C.

That particular bean or object of class C will be shared for all the classes whether it's class A or B or whatever.

Comment: This is the default behavior, however it actually depends on the scope defined for class C.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, right. I needed to mention that as well. :)